# Specialized term for pig excrement?

Tags: single-word-requests, animals

Horse manure, cow dung, bear scat, chicken droppings...  Many animals have special words for their poo.  I can't remember one for pigs though, even though they're a pretty significant species for us.

Is it just 'pig manure'?

Comment: This question very likely has no answer. Also, none of your example words are actually animal-specific in their definitions.

Comment: Note that if it's not specified, "manure" is more general. [MW defines it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manure) as "material that fertilizes land, *especially :* refuse of stables and barnyards consisting of livestock excreta with or without litter."

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pig+shit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpig%20shit%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Much as @Jim points out above, there is the idiom, ["Happy as a pig in..."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/happy_as_a_pig_in_shit) ...which would suggest a general term of some sort is best.

Comment: @wavemode.  If such a word doesn't exist, that **is** an answer.

Comment: None of the words that you list is actually a specialized term for that particular animal's excrement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [list of such terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feces#Feces_of_animals). It does not list a specific words for pigs, so absent evidence to the contrary, I assume there is no specialised term. There are two terms for describing feces of animals in general (using the same Wikipedia list as the source):

**Dung** to refer to the bulk material and **droppings** to refer to the individual *pieces*.

From that same Wikipedia list, it seems *manure* is only used to refer to horse feces or feces used as a fertilizer.

Comment: Re manure, see my comment under the main question :-)

Comment: I _think_ dung is for large herbivores only: cows, elephants, horses, camels.

Comment: Close enough.  There **are** specialized terms, just like there are specialized terms for many aspects of the animal species we most interact with (female, male, newborn, etc...).  It so happens there is none in English for pig excrement.  FWIW, French has 'purin' for just that and I kept on trying to remember that in English, while forgetting I was actually thinking of  the French word.

Answer (score 1):

The only animal-specific name for excrement I can think of is that of rabbits and hares, whose [digestive system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit#Digestion) produces two types: hard and soft pellets; the latter, which are reingested, also have the scientific name [*cecotropes*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cecotrope). This performs the same digestive function as in ruminants — cattle and sheep — without the extra internal organs.

Other word choices seem to depend on how human use or interact with animal excreta. When used for [fuel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_dung_fuel), the word is *dung*, and a dung bettle never seems to encounter *manure*. Small animals, whether birds or rodents, usually produce *droppings*, but so do cockroaches. Flies produce *specks*.

[*Chicken* or *poultry litter*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poultry_litter) contains chicken droppings along with feathers, uneaten feed, and bedding materials. In some parts of the US, it is used as supplementary cattle feed.

According to [Random House](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scat?s=t), *scat* is the “excrement of an animal,” but I have only heard the word associated with wild animals, especially those stalked as prey.

If used as fertilizer, there may be regional differences in the choice of *dung* or *manure*. Where I grew up in West Texas, *manure* came, unsurprisingly, from cattle, and if it came from some other animal, it would have to be specified. Does wonders for roses, by the way. *Dung* was a word I heard from nature programs on television: elephants and camels.

If you are a farmer and you have to clean out a stable or barn, you shovel *manure*.